# loopback 3 setTimeout strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I'm confused by this kind of strange behavior from `loopback`. I created a very simple remote method as an example below.

```
Device.getTypes = function(next) {
    let result = {0: {val: 10}};
    setTimeout(function() {
        result[0].wait = true;
    }, 10);
    console.log(result); // {'0': {val: 10}}
    return next(null, result);
};
```

The console prints out exactly what I expected. `result[0].wait` is not defined in this context. But responded JSON data really got me confused.

```
{
    "data":{
        "0":{
            "val": 10,
            "wait": true
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `"wait": true` was there. I then increased delay time to 100. `data[0].wait` was gone. Does `loopback` perform a delay in the back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is nothing to do with loopback, it is a node.js feature. node.js in asynchronous in nature(and if you want a synchronous code, you need to use some tricks such as Promise, async libraries, ...). but, that's not just it. console.log is an exception and it is a blocking i/o call, and in your case when your setTimeout is called with a value less than the blocking time, you get `"wait": true` in your result, otherwise it returns the result before making that change.

Comment: yes, I often use async or put `next()` inside asynchronous callback function, mostly when querying database. But yesterday, I put `next()` in the wrong place as you can see but the server still responds the result with extended data. Your answer make things a bit clearer to me, then I mark it as accepted. Thanks.